# JSON output thumbnails and other image sizes

Tags: templates, plugin

I'm currently using this plugin: **http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/json**

It does pretty much everything I want it to-do but unfortunately it doesn't out put images and all the different versions of that image.

I have edited the plugin to return the data I want but What I have written seems a bit messy and isn't very flexible.

Does anyone have a better solution to editing the **JSON** output of this plugin to include all image sizes.

Or is this a built in feature I missed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do these image sizes come from? Are they being created via the manipulations set in the File Upload Preferences? Created by a fieldtype or plugin?

Comment: I am setting them under the file preferences so I can call them like so {image:thumb}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this plugin which allows me more flexibility: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/json-encode